# JPA Criteria "locate" ignoring "from" parameter

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have a table `SASDOSSIERS` with one column `apentrytext` which has one value `6.8.3 Dossiers "A" , SAS,  Fürsorgeleistungen an Auslandschweizer` which I need to select after the last `,`: `Fürsorgeleistungen an Auslandschweizer`. If I perform the following query in sql, the select is correct:

```
SELECT distinct TRIM(SUBSTR(apentrytext,INSTR(apentrytext,',',-1)+1)) from SASDOSSIERS;
```

Whereas, if I try to use the equivalent in [jpa critera](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/criteria/CriteriaBuilder)

```
cq.multiselect(
            cb.trim(
                    cb.substring(
                            sasdossier.get(Sasdossier_.apentrytext),
                            cb.sum(
                                    cb.locate(sasdossier.get(Sasdossier_.apentrytext), cb.literal(","), cb.literal(Integer.valueOf(-1))),
                                    1
                            )
                    )
            )
    ).distinct(true);
```

It ignores totally what I put in the from parameter (I have tried with many different values, eg:-2, -100, 1, 2, 100) and it seems to ignore what I put there, the result is always the same. Moreover, the query generated by hibernate shows that the argument is, indeed, ignored:

```
SELECT DISTINCT trim(BOTH FROM substr(sasdossier0_.apentrytext, instr(sasdossier0_.apentrytext, ?) + 1)) AS col_0_0_
FROM ACCESS_DB.sasdossiers sasdossier0_
WHERE sasdossier0_.apentrytext IS NOT NULL
```

It seems like a legit bug, but I cuouldn't find anybody that has the same error before, so, am I doing something wrong? should I report the error?

Thank you.